# Using preg_match and str_replace to verify link

Tags: php

I'm building a simple blog script that allows the users to put html in the content (I'm using htmlpurifier). I want the users to be able to post image urls, but only from imgur. How can I best approach this method using preg_match and str_replace?

Example. If image url is not from imgur then use str_replace and delete it.

---

After playing around with DOMDocument (Jack adviced on the chat to use DOM instead) I came up with the solution to my own question.

```
// let's pretend <img src="" /> is inside content
$content = $_POST['content'];

$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($content);
libxml_clear_errors();

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    if (parse_url($img->getAttribute('src'), PHP_URL_HOST) != 'i.imgur.com') {
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(invalid image provider) ", $content); 
    echo $content;
    } else {
        echo $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yet?  If so, please show it.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143202/any-preg-match-to-extract-image-urls-from-text

Comment: Would something like this do the job?if(!preg_match('/http:\/\/i\.imgur\.com\[^&]+/', $url)) { $err = 'Not valid'; }

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Thanks for encouraging me to dig deeper and figure it out by myself hehe. I shared my solution, in case someone in the future has the same question. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the URL:

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$suffix = 'imgur.com';
if (substr_compare($host, $suffix, -strlen($suffix)) != 0) {
    // not an imgur.com link
}
```