# Detect and extract image url from text and html tags

Tags: php, html

How can i detect if there is some image html tag inside a text and extract just the url of the image ?

Eg.

Extract this url :

```
http://
www.someurl.com/somefileprocessor.php/12345/somedir/somesubdir/someniceimage.j
pg
```

from this tag (this tag can be inside another bunch of text and/or html)

```
<img title="Some nice title" border="0"
hspace="0" alt="some useful hint" src="http://
www.someurl.com/somefileprocessor.php/12345/somedir/somesubdir/someniceimage.j
pg" width="629" height="464" />
```

Thank's in advance
Ângelo

Comment: Seems like the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143202/any-preg-match-to-extract-image-urls-from-text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick attempt at an `<img/>` tag specific regex:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]*?\s+src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*?>/i', $str, $matches);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/29S9mT)

Comment: There should be at least one whitespace between img and src attribute. You should add a \s+. This fails: <img data-active-src="active.png" src="standard.png">

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CRUL` to get content and then extract all `img` tags from content.
to get data by `curl`:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

then use regular expression to extract data.

```
^https?://(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$
```

this helps you to extract all image urls(in img tag or not).

If you need crawler ,you can use [PHPCrawl](http://cuab.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's a lot for the awnswers, as i learn some more PHP. I try this quick and dirty way, it also extracts the image url

```
$imageurl    = strstr($title, 'src',FALSE);
$imageurl    = strstr($imageurl,'"',FALSE);
$imageurlpos = strpos($imageurl,'"');
$imageurl    = substr($imageurl,$imageurlpos+1);
$imageurlpos = strpos($imageurl,'"');
$imageurl    = substr($imageurl,0,$imageurlpos);
```