# extract photo from rss with [enclosure] and [@attributes] and put in php

Tags: php, xml, rss

how can i extract photos from this code

```
[enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[@attributes] => Array ( [url] => http://cdn.isna.ir/d/2016/11/10/3/57383183.jpg 
[length] => 129634
[type] => image/jpeg ) )
```

i have tried this

```
echo "<img src=\"" .$item['enclosure']['url'][1]."\">";
```

but it give me error

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. 
This is not a code request forum. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for learn how you can improve your question.

Comment: Also, this might be able to nudge you in one of many directions that could solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143202/any-preg-match-to-extract-image-urls-from-text

Comment: not solved yet.